# How to use bullseye with Qt( MinGW )?

Tags: qt, mingw, bullseye

I have a project in Qt which consists of the set of projects. Projects is building via MinGW and it does not create any .cov file.
I installed bullseye and enabled coverage build but it still does not create *.con file if I try to set path variable like

```
C:\Program Files\BullseyeCoverage\bin;%PATH%
```

the build is constantly failing I always get

```
gcc: CreateProcess: No such file or directory
```

The file to build whole project is following :

```
    d:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.7.4\mingw\bin\qmake.exe Simulator.pro -r -spec win32-g++ "CONFIG+=release"
PATH=D:\QtSDK\mingw\bin\;%PATH%
D:\QtSDK\mingw\bin\mingw32-make -f ./Makefile
```

How can I measure code coverage? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If somebody interested in this question - I already figured it out.
Here is a solution - 
To set bullseye interceptors before your gcc compiler just replace variables

```
QMAKE_CC = %Bullseye gcc path%
QMAKE_CXX = %Bullseye g++ path%
```

This variable should be defined in *.pro file or in gcc config file, which is located in

```
%QTSDKPath%\Desktop\Qt\4.7.4\mingw\mkspecs\win32-g++\ // if you are using gcc from win32
```

You also need to set environment variable:

```
BULLSEYE_PATH=%PATH TO REAL COMPILER%
```